# Converting System.IO.Stream to java.io.InputStream

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am using a library for a Xamarin Android project in C#. The object I want to instantiate takes 2 parameters of type java.io.InputStream and java.io.OutputStream. 
The BluetoothSocket's input and output streams are of type System.Io hence the conversion returns an error. Something like the following piece of code

```
public static void Connect(string address)
    {
        BluetoothDevice device = mBtAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(address);
        BluetoothSocket socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
        socket.Connect();
        mBtSocket = socket;

        java.io.InputStream input = socket.InputStream;//cannot implicitly convert
        java.io.OutputStream output = socket.OutputStream;//cannot implicitly convert
        cmd = new DP25ROU(input, output);
    }
```

Is there a valid way of converting the input/output to their respective counterparts of java.io?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access `InputStream` and `OutputStream` this way:

```
Java.IO.InputStream input = ((Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker)socket.InputStream).BaseInputStream;

Java.IO.OutputStream output = ((Android.Runtime.OutputStreamInvoker)socket.OutputStream).BaseOutputStream;
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, there is a built in converter from .net stream to java.io stream

Example:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:/test/test.pdf", FileMode.Append);
java.io.InputStream javaStream = new ikvm.io.InputStreamWrapper(fileStream);
```